# Different results when performing feature selection with XGBOOST

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

```
# use feature importance for feature selection
from numpy import loadtxt
from numpy import sort
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
# load data
dataset = loadtxt('.\\DataSets\\pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=",")
# split data into X and y
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# split data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=7)
# fit model on all training data
model = XGBClassifier(eval_metric = "error")
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# make predictions for test data and evaluate
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
# Fit model using each importance as a threshold
thresholds = sort(model.feature_importances_)
for thresh in thresholds:
    # select features using threshold
    selection = SelectFromModel(model, threshold=thresh, prefit=True)
    select_X_train = selection.transform(X_train)
    # train model
    selection_model = XGBClassifier(eval_metric = "error")
    selection_model.fit(select_X_train, y_train)
    # eval model
    select_X_test = selection.transform(X_test)

    select_X_test = X_test[:, 0:select_X_test.shape[1]]*0 + select_X_test

    y_pred = selection_model.predict(select_X_test)
    predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
    print("Thresh=%.3f, n=%d, Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (thresh, select_X_train.shape[1], accuracy*100.0))
```

You can get the dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/kumargh/pimaindiansdiabetescsv

Run the code above, the results are:

```
Accuracy: 74.02%
Thresh=0.088, n=8, Accuracy: 74.02%
Thresh=0.089, n=7, Accuracy: 71.65%
Thresh=0.098, n=6, Accuracy: 71.26%
Thresh=0.098, n=5, Accuracy: 74.41%
Thresh=0.100, n=4, Accuracy: 74.80%
Thresh=0.136, n=3, Accuracy: 71.26%
Thresh=0.152, n=2, Accuracy: 71.26%
Thresh=0.240, n=1, Accuracy: 67.32%
```

However when commentting out the line `select_X_test = X_test[:, 0:select_X_test.shape[1]]*0 + select_X_test`. This line is meanless, but the results are:

```
Accuracy: 74.02%
Thresh=0.088, n=8, Accuracy: 60.63%
Thresh=0.089, n=7, Accuracy: 61.02%
Thresh=0.098, n=6, Accuracy: 59.45%
Thresh=0.098, n=5, Accuracy: 57.87%
Thresh=0.100, n=4, Accuracy: 63.39%
Thresh=0.136, n=3, Accuracy: 56.30%
Thresh=0.152, n=2, Accuracy: 57.87%
Thresh=0.240, n=1, Accuracy: 67.32%
```

what's the difference, a bug? I think the first result is right.
Whether setting up a seed or not doesn't effect the difference.What makes the  difference is the line  `select_X_test = X_test[:, 0:select_X_test.shape[1]]*0 + select_X_test`

Comment: Without reading all the details, I would start with setting up a seed

Comment: that lline is not meaningless, you disable some feature with the *0 multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Your  `XGBClassifier` is not seeded so it will give different results. Instead you can use below to get reproduceable results.

```
XGBClassifier(eval_metric = "error", random_state=3)
```

Comment: Can not get reproduceable results by such settings